# what is 'this' constructor, what is it for

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, this

I'm in the learning process and I have a question I havent been able to find a satisfactory answer for.

`this` I need a rundown on it. I keep seeing it and people have suggested fixes for my code that use it. I really have no idea what exactly it does. If someone would be so kind as to give me a basic rundown on it I would be really happy.

Comment: @ripdaddy69 right, the OP can look at java documentation to find out what C# was like 20 years ago.

Comment: @HighCore the question had no specific language attached to it at the time.

Comment: @ripdaddy69 no problem dude, history books from the stone age are always an interesting reading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's used to refer to another constructor in the same class.  You use it to "inherit" another constructor:

```
public MyClass() {}

public MyClass(string something) : this() {}
```

In the above, when the second constructor is invoked, it executes the parameterless constructor first, before executing itself.  Note that using `: this()` is the equivalent of `: base()`, except it refers to a constructor in the same class, instead of the parent class.

There's an article about constructors [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which provides a usage example:

```
public Employee(int annualSalary)
{
    salary = annualSalary;
}

public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
    : this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's used to invoke another constructor in the class:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() : this("AmazingMrBrock")
    {

    }

    public Test(string name) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword is used in many context and giving a complete answer will be possible only replicating the entire authoritative source. [The C# Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dk1507sz(v=vs.120).aspx